# How to Select Element by Class and Retrieve its ID in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Consider this code:

```
   d3.selectAll("#treemap rect").on("click", function(){
      msa = d3.select(this).attr('id');
      console.log(msa);
    });
```

HTML:

```
<div id="treemap" ...>
    <rect class="node" id="cityName" ...>
    <rect class="node" id="cityName" ...>
    <rect class="node" id="cityName" ...>
    ...
</div>
```

Also, here is the code that creates the Tree Map structure:

```
var node = div.datum(newRoot[0]).selectAll(".node")
          .data(treemap.nodes)
          .enter().append("rect")
            .attr("class", "node")
            .attr("id", function(d){
              return d.cityname ? d.cityname.replace(/[\W\s]/g,"")+"-"+d.stusps: null;
            })...//The rest is inconsequential for this problem.
```

Now `msa = d3.select(this).attr('class');` returns "node" which is expected. However the ID on that element is the name of a city, and the above JavaScript code returns null and I can see that the ID is there in the DOM. Why doesn't the .attr() method accept "id" as well as "class" and, how do I get at the ID?

Furthermore, I could just use another library with my stack like JQuery to grab the ID, but I want to do it using D3. It might be the purist in me ;)

I have looked [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections) and still don't see it. Any ideas, thanks?

**Update:**

One suggestion was to append an SVG to the div and then create the tree map benieth the SVG tag like so:

```
   var div = d3.select("#dashboardA").append("div")
      .style("position", "relative")
      .attr("id", "treemap");

div = div.append("svg")
  .style("width", (width + margin.left + margin.right) + "px") //1220px
  .style("height", (height + margin.top + margin.bottom) + "px") //558px
  .style("margin", "auto")
  .style("left", margin.left + "px")
  .style("top", margin.top + "px");
```

**Result:**

The tree map is now not visible or accessible. Also, most of the examples I have found of tree maps all create the tree map with no SVG tag whatsoever. Here is an official [example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063582). Are they all wrong?

Comment: I know this is just a toy example but what's the actual structure? You aren't putting svg:rect into html:div, and it may be that somewhere along the way you're putting rects into g.node or something along those lines. Because d3.select(this).attr("id") should give you the node id.

Comment: @Elijah Actually I am not creating an svg tag, just straight up rect tags beneath the dev above. So that is the structure as it stands in the DOM. Are you saying that it missing an svg tag is part of the problem?

Comment: Clarifying question, so the Tree map code gives the above result, and you can see that the id attr is present in the elements, right?

Comment: @FranciscoGarcia Correct. I can see that the ID is present in the DOM.

Comment: @Mr.Concolato, shot in the dark, is it ID or id. Once I had an issue where the code that was creating the slices of a Pie was adding attr ID instead of id or Id, and the element read ID="whateer" but trying to access it was throwing an unexpected result

Comment: @FranciscoGarcia No it is id. There are no errors. It is just retuning null. I was thinking that what I was doing was wrong but, Elijah claimed that it should work. :/

Comment: Yeah, it should, that's why I mentioned the possibility. Again, just a shot in the dark.

Comment: @Mr.Concolato, the example you link to is placing `divs` in `divs`, it doesn't need an `svg` tag.  You are placing `rects` in a div.  A rect is an SVG element, it needs to be in an SVG tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You markup is invalid.  You can't have an SVG `rect` in an HTML `div`; the rects need to be nested in an svg container.

Following that, with this code then:

```
d3.selectAll("#treemap rect").on("click", function(){
  msa = d3.select(this).attr('id');
  console.log(msa);
});
```

What are you clicking on?  The invalid markup produces no rects and nothing to click on.

So ... [if you place the rects in an `svg` your code works as expected](http://plnkr.co/edit/DBnOoUZAmms6xF60Ks8P?p=preview).

Comment: Not quite. Either you missed something or you have to go deeper/provide more information. Please see my update, thanks.

Comment: @Mr.Concolato, you'll need to create a reproducible example.  My example above shows that with your mark-up and your click handler things work as expected.

Comment: Based on your experience, you might be correct, but based on the example in my question from D3's website, I am not able to get that example to work with the SVG tag. When I remove the tag, the tree map shows up. Not sure why? I will give an upvote for your recommendation though.